Путь не является файлом
У меня в файле c_cpp_properties.json ошибка, пишет "Путь не является файлом: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin". Но в папке bin нету gcc как этого требует программа и даже в папке usr\bin\gcc нету его. Вроде бы компилятор я установил правильно. Я просто новичек в этой сфере так что может что то не так сделал.
Вот код
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
        "includePath": [
           "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin",
        "cStandard": "${default}",
        "cppStandard": "${default}",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
        "compilerArgs": [
            ""
        ]
    }
],
"version": 4

}

"Вроде бы компилятор я установил правильно" Значит не установили. Как вы его устанавливали?

"Я просто новичек" - ставьте Visual Studio, там в комплекте и компилятор будет и прочие инструменты нужные.

Я устанавливал его через оф сайт VS Code. Проверил в командной строке все норм
